# C#/.NET: XDocument always has the wrong encoding

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I've got a problem with the XDocument class. I am loading information of online XML API, for my first WP8.1 App, like this:

```
        try
        {
            var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(_url);
            return xmlDoc;
        }
        catch (XmlException)
        {
            HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await http.GetAsync(new Uri(_url));
            var webresponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var content = XmlCharacterWhitelist(webresponse);
            var xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(content);
            return xmlDoc;
        }
```

But both ways are returning the wrong encoding. For example German umlauts are shown the wrong way. Every XML file I load has

xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"

in the top line. Any ideas?

Comment: I fixed it by reading it as a Buffer/Byte-Array and then change it to UTF-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than read the data into a byte array and decoding it yourself, just read it as a stream and let `XDocument.Load` detect the encoding from the data:

```
using (HttpClient http = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var response = await http.GetAsync(new Uri(_url)))
    {
        using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        {
            return XDocument.Load(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Those are many nested usings right there. ;) I will try it, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by doing this:

```
        HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
        var response = await http.GetAsync(new Uri(_url));
        var buffer = await response.Content.ReadAsBufferAsync();
        byte[] byteArray = buffer.ToArray();
        string content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

        var xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(content);
        return xmlDoc;
```

Answer (score -1):

Using an XmlReader should resolve issue

```
           string content = "your xml here";
            StringReader sReader = new StringReader(content);
            XmlTextReader xReader = new XmlTextReader(sReader);
            XDocument xmlDoc = (XDocument)XDocument.ReadFrom(xReader);
```

Comment: That won't fix an incorrect encoding issue - it will be broken before the content is read.

Comment: Jon : We are both correct.  If you were reading from a file the XmlTextReader would of worked.  What I forgot is the StringReader would corrupt the text.

Comment: No, StringReader doesn't corrupt the text - the problem would be present in the `content` variable, by the sounds of it. I'm not saying that using XmlReader is a bad idea - but using it in the way you've suggested won't help.

Comment: String reader corrupts the text because it defaults to ASCII encoding that removes non printable characters and packs unicode characters incorrectly.

Comment: That's not true at all. StringReader doesn't so any conversions at all - it *starts* with text, and returns text - where do you think there's any conversion going on? Were you thinking of `StreamReader`? That decodes binary data to text - but it defaults to UTF-8, not ASCII.